# what is the best practise to store user information obtained from cognito authentication in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

In frontend, I will do the registration and login using cognito.

Let's assume I have a "User" table to store user information.
Username(using cognito username) will be the partition key in the table.
Every user has different permissions which would be store as list of strings, such as ["admin", "viewer"] etc, so there will be an attribute called "permissions"

There is the registration and login flow I am considering:

1. Registration in frontend > Cognito registration(await Auth.signUp) > if successful, store user information in dynamodb by using lambda function.
   The request body of POST request to dynamodb will like this.

```
{
   username: xxxxx (partition key),
   permissions: ["admin", "viewer"],
   isConfirmed: 0
}
```

2.If user is confirmed in Cognito User Pool, send PATCH request to change isConfirmed to 1

3.user login in frontend > Cognito login(await Auth.signIn) > query for user data by username in dynamodb

A few questions below.
a)Is there any problems in registration and login flow that I can improve?
b)for (2), can I trigger the lambda function if the confirmation is done?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation about [Cognito triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html).  You could use the [post confirmation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html) trigger to execute a lambda once your user passes the confirmation step of your sign-up process.  This would let you avoid the 2nd step of your proposed solution (sending a `PATCH` request) and just worry about the logic of storing user info in the database.

Comment: Such a great advice! But what do you mean of worrying the logic of storing user info in the database? Do u have better advice? Thanks so much!

Comment: You can create a lambda that Cognito executes after users confirm their accounts.  That lambda will receive an event from Cognito that will contain the user information which you can then insert into DynamoDB.  You can set the post-confirmation trigger directly in the Cognito console.

Comment: So U mean I should insert user information before confirmation?

Comment: You could insert user info before the user is confirmed if you'd like, that would be a different trigger. The Cognito post-confirmation trigger will execute your lambda code only after the user confirms their account, which sounds like what you need.  You need to create a lambda that inserts user data to DDB and tell Cognito to run it during the post-confirmation trigger.  Cognito will execute the lambda once the user is confirmed.  All your client needs to do is offer a way for the user to confirm their account and Cognito handles the rest.